# Recover data from column when I changed de column type MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I changed the data type column in MySQL and I have lost all the data that it contains. The data type that I had it was `TIME` and it was changed to `TIMESTAMP`. MySQL put it all in the format **00:00:00**.

I would like to recover this data to the previous status, is it posibble?

I'm trying to remember that in Oracle was possible if you are looking for the metadata to recover something lost.

Thank you guys.

Comment: check possibility of recovery by Database Recovery Tools like 'EaseUS '. see: https://www.easeus.com/data-recovery/data-recovery-software/free-mysql-database-recovery.htm

Comment: I am gonna have a look, thanks!  but I am still prefering to do this via command